# How to use JavaScript constructor-class variables in if / else conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, constructor

I'm getting an error message in the console that "this.cardPlace" and "this.flipPlace" are both undefined. I ran a console.log before the if/else condition and they were both functioning correctly. There's probably something small that I'm missing. (I'm quite new to coding, so please don't stone me, haha!) Thanks for your help!

```js
class CardSection {
    constructor(_cardPlace, _flipPlace, _cat_section, _flipButton, _min, _max) {
        this.cardPlace = _cardPlace;
        this.flipPlace = _flipPlace;
        this.flippy = function() {
            if (_flipButton.value == "side-one") {
                this.flipPlace++;
                _flipButton.value = "side-two";
                document.getElementsByClassName("location").innerHTML = "Answer Side";
                _cat_section.src = "cards/" + this.cardPlace + "-" + this.flipPlace + ".tiff";
            } else if (_flipButton.value == "side-two") {
                this.flipPlace--;
                _flipButton.value = "side-one";
                document.getElementsByClassName("location").innerHTML = "Question Side";
                _cat_section.src = "cards/" + this.cardPlace + "-" + this.flipPlace + ".tiff";
            }
        }; 

...

var cat_section = document.getElementById("catechism-section-1");
var flipButton = document.getElementById("flip-button1");

var sect1 = new CardSection(1, 1, cat_section, flipButton, 1, 9);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw8sz.png)

Comment: How are you calling `flippy()`?  And why is that defined as a `this.flippy` rather than a `flippy(){ ... }` on the class?

Comment: "flippy()" is being called when a button is clicked on the webpage — document.getElementById("flip-button1").addEventListener("click", sect1.flippy);

Comment: `addEventListener('click', sect1.flippy)` is most likely your problem.  Try changing it to `addEventListener('click', () => sect1.flippy())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: It worked—thank you so much! I know that is modern JS syntax. Is there a way to write it in pre-ES6 syntax?

Comment: `addEventListener('click', function(){ sect1.flippy(); });`